# elasticsearch: how to sort by list of tags and a numeric field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 documents in a mapping look like this

{
"tags":["a"],
"count":10
}
{
"tags":["a","b","c"],
"count":50
}
{
"tags":["a","c"],
"count":100
}

When I search by tags, say, 
{"should":["tags":"a", "tags":"b"]}

Want the result to be sorted by number of tag match, then by count desc, like this:

{
"tags":["a","b","c"],
"count":50
}
{
"tags":["a","c"],
"count":100
}
{
"tags":["a"],
"count":10
}

How can I achieve this? I tried sort [_score, {"count":"desc"}], however, because of the score values are all different, the {"count":"desc"} part never worked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will sort results by score and by count:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {"tag": "a"}},
                {"term": {"tag": "b"}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        },
        "count": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it won't work, as _score is different for all document, if you read my original post, that's exactly the reason why I ask for help here

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
   "sort": [{"count": "desc"}],
   "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "filter": {
         "bool": {
           "should": [
             {"term": {"tag": "a"}},
             {"term": {"tag": "b"}}
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

use *filter query* to ignore document *score*, and use [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) to sort.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this does sort by count, however, can't put the ones whose tag include both "a" and "b" to the top

Comment: so You want to sort by both score and count? you maybe need [Function Score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to calculate your own score.

Comment: yeah, both sort by score and count, i've been reading function score, just wondering, is there an easy way to round _score into an integer value? or how should I function the score to achieve this type of sort?

Comment: I think you need to design your own weight formula to calculate.